# "The memory could not be written" error in virtualbox on Windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, memory

so I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on VirtualBox and I have windows 10 1903 running as host, and this error started happening since I installed the VM, I'll be working normally and all things going well, then this error shows up:

The instructions at 0x00007FFCC3008161 referenced memory at 0x0000000000000000. The memory could not be written,
Click on OK to terminate the program.

and the machine status is Aborted

I zipped the log file in a [zip file](https://gofile.io/?c=Kr6tS1) if you click the link it will download it automatically,

Specs of the machine:

- Acer Predator Helios 300 2018.
- i7 8750H
- GTX 1060
- 16GB DDR4 2666MHz
- 256 NVMe SSD

It is running the latest version of virtualbox and the latest extension pack. I assigned 3 cores and the execution cap to 100%, and it has 8GB of virtual memory, 128MB video memory, and 3D acceleration enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me specifically when restarting the VM, and after making a research seems to be a [known issue](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13580) not [VirtualBox specific](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDUT2q7eiPw) (but common solutions will not usually solve it because it is a VB bug) that it is not yet resolved or well documented.
Many suggest [changing versions](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=79136&start=15) [update drivers](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=98825) and generally update the OS but in some cases, this will not solve the issue.

In those cases, the problem can be caused by several reasons but you can start by simply deactivate the 3D acceleration, this will probably solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after coming back from the holidays, with my last log-in nearly two weeks earlier. My solution in Virtual Box was to go to:

File > Quit (or Ctrl + Q)

A warning message appeared to say that a shutdown will commence and may affect any unsaved data from applications still open. (In my case, I only had the command line open so that was fine so I selected OK).

I then selected my virtual instance in Virtual Box and selected Start again, and I could regain access.

Through this process Virtual Box restarted my VM, rebooting with my account and login. Note, any previously opened applications will now be closed, so any unsaved data will be lost.